# ImportError when importing brightway2

Tags: brightway

I am getting this import error when trying to import brightway:

```
import brightway2 as bw
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-a3ddbb8a34e8> in <module>
----> 1 import brightway2 as bw

/opt/anaconda3/envs/bw2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/brightway2/__init__.py in <module>
      1 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*
----> 2 from bw2data import *
      3 from bw2calc import *
      4 from bw2io import *
      5 

/opt/anaconda3/envs/bw2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bw2data/__init__.py in <module>
     31 
     32 from .configuration import config
---> 33 from .project import projects
     34 from .utils import set_data_dir
     35 from .meta import (

/opt/anaconda3/envs/bw2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bw2data/project.py in <module>
      6 from .errors import ReadOnlyProject
      7 from .filesystem import safe_filename, create_dir
----> 8 from .sqlite import PickleField, create_database
      9 from .utils import python_2_unicode_compatible
     10 from fasteners import InterProcessLock

/opt/anaconda3/envs/bw2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bw2data/sqlite.py in <module>
      4 
      5 from peewee import SqliteDatabase, BlobField, Model, TextField
----> 6 from playhouse.shortcuts import RetryOperationalError
      7 import os
      8 try:

ImportError: cannot import name 'RetryOperationalError'
```

I am using macOS system. I have tried reinstalling conda as well but I keep getting the same error, so I am not sure what is wrong. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your version of `bw2data` is very out of date. [Since 2018](https://github.com/brightway-lca/brightway2-data/commit/4c79ef50b7a7fb12cce2961578f7b5bd115988d2#diff-3a6a9d3ad488bd4161386dd9f34cb57d), i.e. version 3.3, this code has changed. Upgrade `bw2data` using either `conda` or `pip`, depending on how you installed it in the first place.

Comment: It is working now after I updated, thanks a lot Chris!